# Fetching data from many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am having 3 tables namely

| category |  | case |  | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| office_id |  |  |  |  |
| category_id | linked to > | category_id |  |  |
|  |  | case_number | linked to > | case_number |
|  |  |  |  | total_cost |

Problem:
I need to fetch the total number of case and their respective cost for every office id which is there in category table

Query I have written:

```
select cm_c_d.case_number,cm_c.office_id,count(*) as case_count from categories as cm_c 
join case as cm_c_d on cm_c.category_id = cm_c_d.category_id 
join cost on cm_c_d.case_number = cost.case_number group by office_id;
```

but I don't think this will provide the desired result as joining all the three tables will increase the row count.

Updated SQL query:

```
select cm_c.office_id
     , count(DISTINCT cm_costs.case_number) as case_count
     , SUM(total_charge) AS overall_cost
  from cm_categories as cm_c
  JOIN cm_case_details as cm_c_d
    on cm_c.category_id = cm_c_d.category_id
  join cm_costs
    on cm_c_d.case_number = cm_costs.case_number
 group by cm_c.office_id
;
```

Comment: I don't think you have tested the query yet but if you have, are you sure you're able to use table named `CASE` without wrapping it in backticks? As I know `CASE` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) and using it in MySQL query without wrapping in backticks will return error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case'`

Comment: If you update the fiddle I provided with insert statements (for special data causing issues), the real tables, etc, post the updated URL here for review and I or someone can update the question, if you are unable.  I've already posted an edit with your adjusted SQL, pending approval.

Comment: Updated fiddle with just a tiny bit of data, as an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=966fb8ba44bb476d4bf97cdac80e7b18

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct case count (adjusted with the new table names):

```
SELECT cm_c.office_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT cm_costs.case_number) AS case_count
     , SUM(total_charge)                    AS overall_cost
  FROM cm_categories   AS cm_c 
  JOIN cm_case_details AS cm_c_d ON cm_c.category_id   = cm_c_d.category_id 
  JOIN cm_costs                  ON cm_c_d.case_number = cm_costs.case_number
 GROUP BY cm_c.office_id
;
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT x)` means count the distinct number of x values for each group.

Also notice we needed to quote the `case` table name.  As mentioned in prior comments, that's a reserved word.  I suggest avoiding use of reserved words as identifiers (table, column, etc names).

I've removed case_number from your `SELECT` list because it's not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  That means the design/query does not guarantee that there is at most one case_number for each office_id.

If you want a case_number in the select list, you would need to use a form of aggregation (like `COUNT`), as follows:

```
SELECT cm_c.office_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT cm_costs.case_number) AS case_count
     , SUM(total_charge)                    AS overall_cost
     , MIN(cost.case_number)                AS some_case_number
     , GROUP_CONCAT(cost.case_number)       AS all_cases
  FROM cm_categories   AS cm_c 
  JOIN cm_case_details AS cm_c_d ON cm_c.category_id   = cm_c_d.category_id 
  JOIN cm_costs                  ON cm_c_d.case_number = cm_costs.case_number
 GROUP BY cm_c.office_id
;
```

Be careful of `GROUP_CONCAT` for very large sets, since that result column width could get rather wide.

Here's the test case, with necessary adjustments:

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=966fb8ba44bb476d4bf97cdac80e7b18)

For more detail on `GROUP BY` and `functional dependence`, see the following links:

[group-by-handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

[group-by-functional-dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: It would be good to add a bit of explanation to this answer.  What is simple to you is not always obvious to the OP/researchers

Comment: The problem with this query is that the number of records in case table are different then this query is providing as it's considering those rows only which are there in the categories table. For example: may be the case that there is only one row for category id 1 in the categories table but in the case table it has 5 and this query is skipping that scenario.

Comment: @ArunSharma You used `inner join`s in your logic.  If you want results associated with items that have no matches in some tables, you'll need `outer join` behavior.  Can you provide some test data related to any special cases and expected results?  Feel free to change the fiddle I provided.